# Map<String, List<? extends AbstractType>>

Tags: java, list, generics, dictionary

I was looking all around Stack Overflow but I don't know if that's possible but here is my question:

I have two types `A` and `B` extending from `AbstractType`,
then I want a `Map` with both type of object inside like this:

```
Map<String,List<? extends AbstractType>> map = new HashMap();
map.put("toto",new Arraylist<A>);
map.put("sacha",new Arraylist<B>);
List<A> a = (List<A>)map.get("toto");
```

I have a safety warning which is completely understandable, but that's the best way I found to make this work.

The only safety option I found was to have two distinct lists, but I would rather prefer a map to avoid multiple if case.

I hope someone will have an idea.

Comment: How do you know that `map.get("toto")` is a `List<A>` and not a `List<B>` or `List<C>`?

Comment: Why don't you create corresponding POJOs and override hashCode and equals methods as you wish and keep a Set

Comment: Please elaborate on the "multiple if case" idea. Do you know somehow that "toto" automatically means `List<A>`? Or do you need to test the value that's in `map` to find out whether it's of the `A` or `B` variety?

Comment: Yes I know that the compiler doesn't know that the return type is a list of A or B or C. But for me when I call that method from one part of the code, I know that the return type is a list of A, and from an other part is a list of B.

Comment: That's kind of why I don't understand what you mean by "multiple if case". Since you already know, what kind of "if" stuff will you need to do?

Comment: Yes you are right, There is not "if". I was just saying that because I thought this will create a lot of if. This example was just to see if a workaround of this exists before it was going to help me. But I create 2 lists and I duplicate some fonction, but it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `instanceof` to always make sure that you don't get in some trouble. Here is an example, you can modify it as per your requirements:

```
Map<String,List<? extends AbstractType>> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("toto",new ArrayList<A>());
        map.put("sacha",new ArrayList<B>());

        List<? extends AbstractType> objList = (List<? extends AbstractType>) map.get("toto");
        List<A> a = null;
        List<B> b = null; 
        if(objList.size() > 0 && objList.get(0) instanceof A){
            a = (List<A>) objList;
        }else if (objList.size() > 0 && objList.get(0) instanceof B){
            b = (List<B>) objList;
        }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: A check is present! :)

Comment: Right, but if the `List` is empty there's nothing to check. Both `a` and `b` will be `null`.